# Why are SWITCH and IF different in terms of Variable assignement

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I am currently using IF-Statements most of the time, but I am increasingly fond of the switch case statement, because sometimes it is a lot more readable.
But I am wondering why the Compiler does not understand switch as well as an `if`. 
An example:

```
bool decision = false;
IEnumerable<string> toBeAssigned;

if (decision)
{
   toBeAssigned = getValuesA();
}
else
{
   toBeAssigned = getValuesB();
}

foreach (var elem in toBeAssigned )
{
       // do something
}
```

This should compile fine and toBeAssigned can be used in the foreach without a problem.

BUT:

```
bool decision = false;
IEnumerable<string> toBeAssigned;

switch(decision)
{
  case true:       
     toBeAssigned = getValuesA();
     break;
  case false:       
     toBeAssigned = getValuesB();
     break;
}

foreach (var elem in toBeAssigned )
{
// do something
}
```

Does not compile for me - the compiler complains that the Value for toBeAssigned is never assigned.
Since both should compile to the same IL, I am curious why the Compiler treats both cases differently.

Comment: With switch compiler doesn't know that your `case`s are exhaustive. It doesn't check this fact. Therefore, because you have no `default` in your `switch` it thinks that there is a way when `toBeAssigned` is not assigned. Add `default` case instead of `false` and it will work.

Comment: Slightly-offtopic, regarding the specific case you quote:`switch` makes sense when there are more-than-two potential options but, when there can only ever be two results, I would suggest that the `if` version is significantly more readable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are missing the `default` case in your switch statement. The same would happen if you had written:

```
if (decision)
{
   toBeAssigned = getValuesA();
}
else if (!decision)
{
   toBeAssigned = getValuesB();
}
```

This happens, because the compiler doesn't know how much cases there are and always assumes that you have not covered them all, unless you have a `default` statement, which basically sais "if all other cases are not met, do this". The same goes for `if` and `else`: `if(...)` and `else if(...)` are your "case: " and `else` is your "default: "

Answer (score 11):

Your `if` statement covers all possible cases but the compiler does not realise that the `switch` does that too: you're missing a `default` case.

The compiler thinks that there is a possibility that `toBeAssigned` might not be set to anything, so it emits the error.